# Fastest data structure for residual graphs

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph-algorithm

I am trying to implement a flow algorithm with thousands of nodes and edges, therefore I need efficient data structures. Currently I do the following:

Structure Node:

```
Double Linked Array (Parents) //Edges that enter the node (basicaly a tuple that contains a pointer to the parent node and the weight, current flow of the edge
Double Linked Array (Sons) //Edges that leave the node
```

The problem is, when I perform a BFS, given a node v I need to look at the edges in the [residual graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem#Solutions) (basically backwards edges for the edges you send flow on), that leave v. Because I can have parallel edges I need to always know which backwards edge comes from which forward edge.

Currently I am solving the problem by first handling all edges in Sons(v), and then I defined a map that gives me the index of the Parents(w) in the destination node w of all those edges. Therefore I get the backwards edge I stored and can perform my algorithm. However those maps have log(E) access time which slows my algorithm down way too much. How should I approach this problem (the double linked lists are implemented as std::vector)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The representation I use is something like an edge list but with additional information

```
typedef long long dintype;
struct edge{
  edge(int t_ = 0,int n_ = 0, dintype c_ = 0){
    to = t_;
    next = n_;
    cap = c_;
  }
  int to,next;
  dintype cap;
};
const int max_edges = 131010;
const int max_nodes = 16010;
edge e[max_edges];
int first[max_nodes]; // initialize this array with -1
int edges_num;
inline void add_edge(int from,int to, dintype cap){
  if(edges_num == 0){
    memset(first,-1,sizeof(first));
  }
  e[edges_num].to = to;e[edges_num].cap = cap;
  e[edges_num].next = first[from];first[from] = edges_num++;

  e[edges_num].to = from;e[edges_num].cap = 0;
  e[edges_num].next = first[to];first[to] = edges_num++;
}
```

I have used global arrays to be able to explain the idea better. I use this for my [dinitz algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinic%27s_algorithm).

Now a bit of explanation. In the array "e" I hold all the edges. In the array first[v] I hold the index of the first edge going out of v in the array e. If an edge is present in index idx in the array e then the reverse edge is stored in the element with index idx^1.
So this representation enables us to both have a neighbours list(strarting from first[v] and following the next index until it becomes -1) and be able to access the reverse edge in constant time.

Answer (score 4):

```
int src,snk,nnode,nedge;
int fin[100000],dist[100000];//nodes
int cap[100000],next[100000],to[100000];
void init(int s,int sn,int n)
{
    src=s,snk=sn,nnode=n,nedge=0;
    memset(fin,-1,sizeof(fin));
}
void add(int u,int v,int c)
{
    to[nedge]=v,cap[nedge]=c,next[nedge]=fin[u],fin[u]=nedge++;
    to[nedge]=u,cap[nedge]=0,next[nedge]=fin[v],fin[v]=nedge++;
}
bool bfs()
{
    int e,u,v;
    memset(dist,-1,sizeof(dist));
    dist[src]=0;
    queue<int> q;
    q.push(src);
    while(!q.empty())
    {
        u=q.front();
        q.pop();
        for(e=fin[u];e>=0;e=next[e])
        {
            v=to[e];
            if(cap[e]>0&&dist[v]==-1)
            {
                dist[v]=dist[u]+1;
                q.push(v);
            }
        }
    }
    if(dist[snk]==-1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
int dfs(int u,int flow)
{
    if(u==snk)
        return flow;
    int e,v,df;
    for(e=fin[u];e>=0;e=next[e])
    {
        v=to[e];
        if(cap[e]>0&&dist[v]==dist[u]+1)
        {
            df=dfs(v,min(cap[e],flow));
            if(df>0)
            {
                cap[e]-=df;
                cap[e^1]+=df;
                return df;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
int dinitz()
{
    int ans=0;
    int df,i;
    while(bfs())
    {
        while(1)
        {
            df=dfs(src,INT_MAX);
            if(df>0)
                ans+=df;
            else
                break;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

This is my code for dinitz algorithm
here init function initializes the adjacency list
add adds a new edge in the list,fin gives the last node in that adjacency list
so u can access all the elements in the list through following loop

```
for(e=fin[u];e>=0;e=next[e])
{
     v=to[e];
}
```

where u is the node whose adjacent element u want to find
v will give the adjacent element to u
also while finding the max flow u need both forward edge and backward edge
so suppose the forward edge is e
then the backward edge will be e^1 and vice versa, but for that the starting index for the edges should be zero